# Swift Repeat While

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm working with while repeat but it's not working quite as I expected.

It's working up to the point where each array only have a count of 1 but I want it to work the point where the count is 0.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3]
var secondArray = [4, 5, 6]

repeat {
    print("Repeat")
    if array.count > secondArray.count {
        array.removeFirst()
    } else {
        secondArray.removeFirst()
    }
} while array.count != 0 && secondArray.count != 0
```

Comment: Apart from that, you want to replace `&&` by `||`

Comment: @MartinR my real code consists of the same type of things I summarized it. I've updated the code.

Comment: ... and you should never use `.count == 0` in Swift, there is `.isEmpty`

Comment: @MartinR thank you my friend that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You want to run your loop until both arrays are empty, i.e. as long as *one of them* is not empty. Therefore the loop condition must be

```
while array.count != 0 || secondArray.count != 0
```

Also note that your code will crash if both arrays are initially empty.
Better use a `while` loop, where the condition is checked *before*
executing the body:

```
while !array.isEmpty || !secondArray.isEmpty {
    if array.count > secondArray.count {
        array.removeFirst()
    } else {
        secondArray.removeFirst()
    }
}
```

(using `isEmpty`, as mentioned in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

@FredoFredo your all code good just change in your while condition

while array.count != 0 || secondArray.count != 0